# How to remove extras lines using stylesheet from axies in the D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I would like to remove the lines that are linked to the values ​​of the axies only by showing the lines as in the example. What is the class in the stylesheet that removes them in d3.js?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Something like this will do the job in pure CSS: `.tick:not(:first-of-type) > line { display: none }`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [tickSize](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickSize) of the axis to 0.